# Json viewer for mac

Tags: macos

Does anyone know a good free Json viewer for mac?  I just want to be able to see the data organised a bit better then one long piece of text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this add-on for Firefox : [JSONView](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10869/)

> Normally when encountering a JSON
>   document (content type
>   "application/json"), Firefox simply
>   prompts you to download the file. With
>   the JSONView extension, JSON documents
>   are shown in the browser similar to
>   how XML documents are shown. The
>   document is formatted, highlighted,
>   and arrays and objects can be
>   collapsed. Even if the JSON document
>   contains errors, JSONView will still
>   show the raw text.

Answer (score 2):

[jsonpretty](http://github.com/nicksieger/jsonpretty) for pretty-printing JSON at the command line.

```
sudo gem install jsonpretty
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to be able to paste in text and see it prettily formatted with some basic "roll-up" functionality, try https://jsonformatter.org/json-parser.

Update: While trying out Olivier's new beta I responded to a feedback prompt, noting the lack of "roll-up" behavior for unnamed objects and arrays. He emailed me the next morning to say that he'd gone ahead and implemented that right away. Awesome!

Comment: Also just uncovered this one. Less easy-on-the-eyes than Olivier Cuenot's tool, but easier to see the forrest for the trees as, unlike json.parser.online.fr, this one will roll up arrays as well as key-value pairs. http://www.thomasfrank.se/downloadableJS/JSONeditor_example.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jason as an offline app:
http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/35588/jason

Answer (score 1):

If you want a JSON QuickLook viewer integrated into the Finder, you can try [quick look JSON](http://www.sagtau.com/quicklookjson.html).

Answer (score 1):

On Browser, I always use this [JSON Viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/).
If I need to see natively on mac, I use [VisualJSON](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/visual-json/id488709442?mt=12), which also support tree view.

Answer (score 1):

My favourite way to do this (on the commandline) is to define a "pretty printing" alias,

```
alias pp="python -mjson.tool | pygmentize -l js"
```

Then you can just

```
cat file.json | pp
```

If the file is big, pipe this through `less -R`, `-R` allows colouring sequences to pass through unescaped (raw).

The only dependency for this is python (`json.tool` is in the python standard library) and `pygments`. If you don't want colour coding you can leave the `| pygmentize ...` bit out.

Answer (score 0):

If you use TextMate, there is a / are JSON.tmbundles available, such as [this one](http://github.com/textmate/json.tmbundle).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind check hitting the web, check out [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com).

It validates and makes your JSON "pretty". You may want to consider other solutions for larger documents as this is not really scalable.